# How to set the NSLocalizedString for unused UI's In swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

Currently I am working in multi-language selection in our project. We have created a Spanish language- Localizable.strings- (Spanish).

> Base language :  "loading" = "Please wait.."; Spanish :  "loading" =
>   "por favor espera..";

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

But we have an unused(Static values in the storyboard) UI's for some buttons and Label as well.

**And we have added below code in our app and it's working as expected.**

Used UI component:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

self.progressLabel.text = "loading".localized
```

Unused UI components:

```
  @IBOutlet var medicalCardButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var idPassportButton: UIButton!
```

We just created medicalCardButton and idPassportButton but not connected the outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Please check the below image and follow the steps

Step 1:

[image: Add localization from project setting]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

Here I have added the value of button in English language.

[image]

Here I have added the value of button in Russian language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ronak. I have a question where do we access the ObjectID in our code? I have added code below, Please check


struct Constant {
static let sampleButton = "Object_ID"
}